# Splice_after implementation of forward_list

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list, forward-list

In `forward_list` there is a function `splice_after` ([for reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/splice_after)), specifically, function #3 in the link given. How would one go about implementing that considering the `list` is singly linked.

As an exercise, when I implemented it, I had to iterate the list until I reached the node before `first` (so that I can connect `first` to `last`) and again until I reached the node before `last` (so that I can connect the current list's node to the node before `last`). This does not seem terrible efficient to me and was wondering whether there is a better way to do it without iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you misread the somewhat subtle range specification which says that "(first, last)" is moved, **not** "[first, last)" (note the opening parenthesis/bracket). That is, as the name indicates, the splice operation only starts **after** the first object.

The implementation of the function is actually quite simple (if you ignore constness of the iterators and the fact that it might need to deal with allocators being different):

```
void splice_after(const_iterator pos, forward_list& other,
                  const_iterator first, const_iterator last) {
    node* f = first._Node->_Next;
    node* p = f;
    while (p->_Next != last._Node) { // last is not included: find its predecessor
        p = p->_Next;
    }
    first._Node->Next = last._Node;  // remove nodes from this
    p->_Next = pos._Node->_Next;     // hook the tail of the other list onto last
    pos._Node->_Next = f;            // hook the spliced elements onto pos
}
```

This operation has linear complexity because it needs to find the predecessor of `last`.

Comment: You suspect correctly! However, my question still stands. What about the element before the last? It needs to be in the list, which means I'll have to iterate to it.

Comment: Why would have to iterate to the element? You just take the next pointer of `last` and stick it into the next pointer of `first`, obviously after saving it so you can put it into the other list. I guess, I shall update my answer with a potential implementation of the function...

Comment: @Samaursa, You said "so that I can connect the current list's node to the node before last". But I think the current node should be connected to last, not to the node *before* last.

Comment: Well, if it is `(fist, last)` then that means first and last are NOT included. I can connect first to last, that's not the problem. Now for the list being spliced into, I have the element after first as well (`first->m_next`) but what about the element before `last` that I need to be able to connect to the list I am splicing into?

Comment: Oh, yeah. I see now! You do have to iterate. "3) linear in std::distance(first, last)"

Comment: @DietmarKühl, we need to find the element that is just before last. Your code will move the `last` into the list. But we're not supposed to move `last`. More precisely, `last` shouldn't move and nor are any elements after `last` affected; therefore we shouldn't make any change to `last._Node->_Next`

Comment: @AaronMcDaid you are right! I didn't think of this and happily pretended that the range was "(`first`, `last`]" (not the bracket at the end). I think I have fixed the code now (including the statement I had after it). Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: I think @Samaursa pointed it our first :-) I had the same misunderstanding myself at one stage.

Answer (score 2):

(community-wiki, please contribute)

```
 A -> B -> C -> D -> E
           ^
           ^ pos points to C
```

In the `other` list

```
 U -> V -> W -> X -> Y -> Z
      ^              ^
      ^ first        ^ last
```

Call `.splice(pos, other, first, last)`

We are to move W and X into the top list. i.e. everything between, but not including, `first` and `last`. To end up with `A->B->C->W->X->D->E` at the top, and `U->V->Y->Z` at the bottom.

```
auto copy_of_first_next = first->next;
first->next = last;
// the `other` list has now been emptied

auto copy_of_pos_next = pos->next;
pos -> next = first;
while(first->next != last) ++first;
// `first` now points just before `last`
first->next = copy_of_pos_next
```